# Brush tool menu.... Missing?

Tags: sculpting

I am following a tutorial by Flipped Normals and in their video, they use some options available in a tool menu ( Brush ) that I cant find in my blender 2.91

I don't think they are using any addon so... Am I doing something wrong.

[image: This is the menu Im looking for]

[image: This is my Blender version]

Comment: What options are you looking for?

Comment: It is all good. Apologies for the late reply....